# Force to call parent::preExecute() in a symfony action

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, overloading, method-call, enforcement

I have a similar structure like this:

**Parent class**

```
abstract class parentActions extends sfActions
{
   // overloaded from sfActions
   public function preExecute()
   {
     // do some stuff before every action
   }

}
```

**Child class**

```
class someActions extends parentActions
{
  public function preExecute()
  {
     // do some more stuff
     parent::preExecute();
  }
}
```

Now my question is: How can I enforce a call to `parent::preExecute()` in the child method which overwrites it?

Is there maybe some other way in symfony I don't know yet (another method which doesn't overloading or something)?

The parent method needs to be called, or otherwise functionality is broken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what inheritance should do; the child specializes a method while retaining the pre and post conditions. This makes it possible to substitute a parent class with a child class.

Perhaps you could declare empty hooks in the parent class that get implemented in the child class and add `final` to the `preExecute()` declaration to prevent accidental overrides.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I have to stick to the `final` way. :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enforce it. It is the sole responsibility of the child class to decide whether or not to call the parent method.

Answer (score 0):

put it in the abstract class `__constructor()`